# What is the best way to deal with missing values in numeric columns for a decision tree?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, missing-data

I have a dataset that has consists of both categorical and numeric columns. It contains a target variable that is a binary 1 or 0.

I want to use a decision tree to come up with branches that would categorize my dataset, clustering the 1s away from the 0s.

The dataset has N/As in both the categorical and numeric variables.

For the categorical, the fix was easy, I just passed a list of column names for the columns that were categorical and used dummy encoding with dummy_na=True.

```
new_df = pd.get_dummies(old_df,dummy_na=True, columns = categorical_columns)
```

This just gave me a column for each categorical variable to signal a missing value row for each categorical column.

But for numeric, I am not sure. The absence of data in the numeric columns has meaning behind it so I can't impute a mean or a median. I can't input a 0 because 0 is a valid value in the numeric columns as well.

I thought of inputting -9999999.99 into the NAs because it was such an outlier value that maybe it would capture for the decision tree that these values were not in sync with the rest of the numeric values. However, is there a better way of doing this? Is imputing -999999.9 a good way to separate these values away from the rest of the numeric values?

Comment: Decision trees are very old, and also know "weak" learners.  Why did you choose the Decision Tree?

Comment: There are implementation issues that restrict implementing something like NB or Xgboost that could better handle missing data. So I'm sticking with using Decision Trees to give me logic branches that I can use to separate out the population I want. .

Comment: I implementation of shoes do you mean high-volume architecture’s that you’re trying to work with?